# Ford Focus water in oil and is overheating

Tags: engine, ford, overheating, focus

I have white smoke and water coming from my exhaust and car is overheating. Will bleeding make this problem go away?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually a sign you have a blown headgasket. No amount of bleeding (whether yours or the cooling system) is going to fix the issue. It will most likely require major engine work to fix it.